# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory. How to increase batch size?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

I have one GPU: GTX 1050 with ~4GB memory.

I try Mask RCNN with 192x192pix and batch=7. I got an error:  `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory`

I found [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth)

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)

  File "<ipython-input-2-0806c9f06bd0>", line 3
    session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: You need to remove the dots... `session = tf.Session(config=config)`

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed as off-topic, although perhaps it should have been moved to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Environment:
1.CUDA 10.0
2.cuNDD 10.0
3.tensorflow 1.14.0
4.pip install opencv-contrib-python
5.git clone https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow
6.Allowing GPU memory growth

[image]

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the case that your GPU cannot manage the full model (Mask RCNN) with batch sizes like 8 or 16.

I would suggest trying with batch size 1 to see if the model can run, then slowly increase to find the point where it breaks.

You can also use the configuration in Tensorflow, but it will essentially do the same thing - it will just not immediately block all memory when you run a Tensorflow session. It will only take what it needs, which (given a fixed model) will be defined by batch size.

---

You should alter your code example to be:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config)
```

Comment: Max batch size was 4-5 image per epoch.

Comment: Is it a good idea to add `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` to increase my batch size?

Comment: Adding that to your config will not mean you can use a larger batch size, it just means tensorflow will only take the memory it needs from the GPU. If you're using the graphics card for other things too (e.g. powering your laptop's screen)  then it might be a good idea to keep it in the config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter Notebook you should run the following code to clear your GPU memory so that you train perfectly

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

If the problem still persists ,use smaller batch size like 4.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The Python [`gc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) module is not going to affect how TensorFlow allocates memory. For people making static computational graphs with TensorFlow 2.0, the relevant call is [`tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/reset_default_graph).